# Is it thread-safe to write to the same pipe from multiple threads sharing the same file descriptor in Linux?

Tags: multithreading, pipe, posix, ipc, embedded-linux

I have a Linux process with two threads, both sharing the same file descriptor to write data of 400 bytes to the same pipe every 100ms. I'm wondering if POSIX guarantees that this is thread-safe or if I need to add additional synchronization mechanisms to serialize the writing to the pipe from multiple threads (not processes).

I'm also aware that POSIX guarantees that multiple writes to the same pipe from different processes that are less than PIPE_BUF bytes are atomically written. But I'm not sure if the same guarantee applies to writes from multiple threads within the same process.

Can anyone provide some insight on this? Are there any additional synchronization mechanisms that I should use to ensure thread safety when writing to the same pipe from multiple threads using the same file descriptor in Linux?

Thank you in advance for any help or advice!

Comment: Posix requires writes up to PIPE_BUF to be atomic. This by definition includes both threads and processes.

Comment: Thank you for your earlier response. You mentioned that POSIX requires writes up to PIPE_BUF to be atomic for both threads and processes. Could you please provide a reference in the POSIX standard for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the posix standard, on general information](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_01) we read:

> 2.9.1 Thread-Safety
>
> All functions defined by this volume of POSIX.1-2008 shall be thread-safe, except that the following functions need not be thread-safe.

And neither read nor write are listed afterwards. And so indeed, it is safe to call them from multiple threads. This however only means that the syscall won't crash, it doesn't say anything about the exact behaviour of calling them in parallel. In particular, it doesn't say about atomicity.

However in [docs regarding `write` syscall](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2008edition/functions/write.html) we read:

> Atomic/non-atomic: A write is atomic if the whole amount written in one operation is not interleaved with data from any other process. This is useful when there are multiple writers sending data to a single reader. Applications need to know how large a write request can be expected to be performed atomically. This maximum is called {PIPE_BUF}. This volume of POSIX.1-2008 does not say whether write requests for more than {PIPE_BUF} bytes are atomic, but requires that writes of {PIPE_BUF} or fewer bytes shall be atomic.

And in the same doc we also read:

> Write requests to a pipe or FIFO shall be handled in the same way as a regular file with the following exceptions:

and the guarantee about atomicity (when size below PIPE_BUF) is repeated.

Comment: Thank you for your response and for providing the reference. However, I do think that the standard could have been more explicit in stating this fact cleanly like                   "A write is atomic if the whole amount written in one operation is not interleaved with data from any other process or threads"

Comment: @user1020828 you mean the usage of the word "process" without "thread"? Yeah, it is not explicit, but it would be very weird to guarantee thread safety, but atomicity only for processes, not threads. And technically even hard to implement such thing. I think we can treat this is a typo.

Comment: yes. It would not make sense for POSIX to guarantee atomicity for less than PIPE_BUF bytes only for processes, but not for threads. I assume that writes of up to PIPE_BUF bytes to a pipe are guaranteed to be atomic, regardless of whether they are coming from a process or a thread

Answer (score 0):

`man 2 write` (Linux man-pages 6.02) says:

```
   According to POSIX.1-2008/SUSv4 Section XSI 2.9.7 ("Thread Interactions
   with Regular File Operations"):

       All of the following functions shall be atomic with respect to each
       other in the effects specified in POSIX.1-2008 when they operate on
       regular files or symbolic links: ...

   Among  the  APIs  subsequently  listed  are write() and writev(2).  And
   among the effects that should be atomic across threads (and  processes)
   are  updates  of the file offset.  However, before Linux 3.14, this was
   not the case: if two processes that share an open file description (see
   open(2))  perform  a  write() (or writev(2)) at the same time, then the
   I/O operations were not atomic with respect to updating the  file  off-
   set,  with  the  result  that the blocks of data output by the two pro-
   cesses might (incorrectly) overlap.  This problem was  fixed  in  Linux
   3.14.
```

So, it should be safe as long as you're running at least Linux 3.14 (which is almost 9 years old).

Comment: The problem was reported and fixed in this thread: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/53022DB1.4070805@gmail.com/

Comment: Thank you for your earlier response. Just to clarify, does the term 'regular file' include pipes as well in the context of the POSIX standard?